I have two experiments going on two different user bases. My aim is to access whether an experiment is doing better. How to proceed?
I have two experiments going on two different user bases. My aim is to determine which experiment is doing better. I am tracking two metrics on daily level. One is regarding retention - basically out of 100 users who were on our app today, how many came next day. Other is number of activities done by users in the two experiments. I want the activity count to be higher.
One thing to note here is that group size for both experiments can be different. Which statistical test to use given that I take the measurements of these metrics daily and these measurements might not be independent across time.
For comparison, we are tracking above two metrics i.e retention (higher is better) and number of activity events (higher is better) on our app done by the users of the two experiments. If retention and activity count is consistently higher across days for a particular experiment (lets say A), then A is better. One experiment is basically a strategy devised to tweak user behaviour.
We want to figure out which strategy is working better and which statistical test I should do to determine whether the results are statistically significant?

Please explain to us how you are comparing the experiments to determine which one is "better."
